# Assign a struct to another struct inside a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i would like to assign a struct into a field in a struct that it a pointer to a struct.
I will show you down here what i'm saying:

```
typedef struct {

    char *name;

} geometry;

typedef struct sceneGR_tag {
    geometry *g;
    struct sceneGR_tag *next;
} sceneGR;

typedef struct {
    geometry *g;
    int nshapes;

    sceneGR *root;  
} scene;
```

As you can see, `sceneGR` has a geometry *g (so an array of geometry).
Premise that I have already initialized the struct 'scene' with its geometry i would like to copy its geometry into the struct 'sceneGR' and so in the sceneGR->g.

How can i do that in my `for`?:

```
scene *scn; //already initialized with nshapes=6, and so with 6 geometries until g[5];

for(k = 0; k < scn->nshapes; k++) {
    //what can i do here?
}
```

Comment: `scene *scn;` is only declaration. Not initialization.

Comment: do you want a copy or should it point to the same object?

Comment: @Jayesh i can't show you the entire program, trust me that i've already initialized before doing the loop. I didn't write it because is hundreds of line of code.

Comment: @mch i want a copy, so something that every scn->g[k] is copied in every new sceneGR object; So for example: sceneGR *gr0 = scn->g[0], sceneGR *gr1 = scn->g[1] etc.

Comment: @Aerox WHAT ? But you want to attribute a `geometry` to a `sceneGR`. It doesn't make sense. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak it doesn't make sense, but the project where i'm working on, is written by other developers, and my task is to add features on what they already did. So i need to adapt my code on what they have written and not to modify it. Sorry....

Comment: @Aerox did you saw my edit ?

Comment: Yes, it works just locally (inside the function), and i don't know why when i try to print the name in the upper function, it shows a segmentation fault. In other words, i try to do the same thing in an other function but i receive a Segmentation fault (core dumped). I think that posting the entire function might be too much complicated. Let me know if i have to edit and paste it above.

Comment: That's really strange because i do the same thing with an other field, but it just works with it and not in this case :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need a loop ? You just have to do :

```
scn->root->geometry = scn->geometry;
```

But let me know if I it isn't what you want.

**EDIT**

You want to copy each geometry value of `scn->g` in each `sceneGR->g`. But it is weird unless you have a `geometry** g` in your `struct scene`. However, you can do it with your code:

```
scene *scn;
sceneGR *s_list = scn->root;

for(k = 0; k < scn->nshapes; k++) {
    s_list->g = &(scn->g[k]);
    s_list = s_list->next;
}
```

But with a `geometry** g` in your `struct scene`, you can do :

```
scene *scn;
sceneGR *s_list = scn->root;

for(k = 0; k < scn->nshapes; k++) {
    s_list->g = scn->g[k];
    s_list = s_list->next;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's not really what i want to do. Something like: copy scn->g[k] into new defined sceneGR in its scenGR->g because every scene->g[k] is different. so i want to copy it singularly in each different sceneGR

Comment: Ok now it works with the first method that you posted. Thank you so much. I don't understand where the error was precisely. The only thing that i know, is that it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `geometry` is defined so that a bitwise copy makes sense, then :

```
SceneGR *gr = malloc(sizeof *gr);
size_t num_bytes_to_copy = scn->nshapes * sizeof scn->g[0];

gr->next = NULL;
gr->g = malloc( num_bytes_to_copy );
memcpy(gr->g, scn->g, num_bytes_to_copy );
```

If not then you will have to loop through calling the copy-function for each `geometry` object.

Also it's not clear how `SceneGR` is supposed to know how many items are in its array.

Don't forget to `free(gr->g)` when you are destroying a `SceneGR`.